# Is it possible to find element in Binary search tree with parallel travelsar

Tags: c, openmp

Hello i want to ask you is it possible to find element with parallel search in binary search tree? Will  it be faster with parallel or serial? Because for Example tree with root 25  and the element you want to find is 50 there is only right node where you should go and search.And if you use paralell there would be wasted searh in the left node.
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUPNs.png)

Comment: Are you talking about binary tree or binary search tree?

Comment: Binary search tree

Comment: In Binary Search Tree there is only one path you could follow to find your data if it exists. If that is the case, then what use would searching parallely serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binary search tree, a single flow of search is always executed. So, you cannot get any parallel execution stream that can speed up the process. If you are using a forest, then you can deploy a thread for each tree in the forest.

Comment: ty and 1 more question. Is this also valid for PreOrder and PostOrder traversal? Because there is also one path in theese two  traversal

Comment: Yes the answer is same for them as well, as those operations are also sequential in nature.